Wdio right click powerBI
onst gapAnalysRight = await $$(//div[@_ngcontent-ng-c1971078803]//*[text()='Forecast']/parent::div);
  await browser.pause(1000)
  await gapAnalysRight[2].click({ button: 2, x: 300, y: 400 })

im working on powerbI report where i need to right click and drill
i have tried all the posibilities nothing worked.
isExisting :True
isClickable false
right click happening at some other place
Need to right click on ron the forcase element
right click happening at some other place
